# Related dynamic of ODE solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm studying the center-focus problem in dynamic systems, and I'm stuck in this problem.

Consider the differential equation

\begin{cases}\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x,y)\\\frac{dy}{dt} = g(x,y) \end{cases}

Where $f$ and $g$ are analytic functions.

Suppose that I know the solution of this specific ODE

\begin{cases}\frac{dx}{dt} = r(x,y) f(x,y)\\\frac{dy}{dt} = r(x,y) g(x,y) \end{cases}

where $r$ is an analytic function, satisfying $r(x,y) \neq 0$, for all $x$, $y$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$

I'm wondering if there is a connection between the solutions of the first and the second equation, or if at least the solutions of the first ODE have the same dynamic of the second?

What I notice is that if you consider the diferential equation $dy/dx = g(x,y)/f(x,y)$, which give us how the second entry of the solution  is related with the first entry, is the same in both equations, but I can't find a way to use this to show that the above ODE has the same dynamic.

Comment: A time change $\tau$ allows to deduce the latter from the former, such that $$\tau(t)=\int_0^tr(x(s),y(s))ds$$

Comment: Nice change of variable, thx

Comment: Do you know how I use your transformation to conclude that the second equation has a center $\Leftrightarrow$ the  first equation also has a center?

Comment: Once you know that the solution $(\bar x,\bar y)$ to the second system can be written in terms of the solution $(x,y)$ to the first system starting at the same initial conditions $(x_0,y_0)$, as $$\bar x(t)=x(\tau(t))\qquad \bar y(t)=y(\tau(t))$$ where $\tau$ is defined in my first comment, you should explain what is still escaping you.

Comment: I think this does not work, because $\frac{d\overline{x}(t)}{dt}$ $=$ $\frac{dx(\tau(t))}{dt}$ $=$ $ \frac{dx(\tau(t))}{dt} \frac{d\tau(t)}{dt} $ $=$ $f(\overline{x}(t), \overline{y}(t)) r(x(t),y(t))$ $\neq$  $f(\overline{x}(t), \overline{y}(t)) r(\overline{x}(t),\overline{y}(t))$, for the fuction $ \overline{y}(t)$ the same problem occour.

Comment: Indeed, one wants that $$\tau(t)=\int_0^tr(x(\tau(s)),y(\tau(s)))ds$$ and not what I wrote. Shame on me... What I would try then would be to define $(\tau_n)$ recursively by $\tau_0(t)=t$ and, for every $n$,  $$\tau_{n+1}(t)=\int_0^tr(x(\tau_n(s)),y(\tau_n(s)))ds$$ and to show, *à la Gronwall*, that $\tau_n\to\tau$ when $n\to\infty$. Or, to define $\tau$ in one stroke from $(x,y)$, as the unique solution starting at $\tau(0)=0$ of the differential equation $$\tau'(t)=r(x(\tau(t),y(\tau(t)))$$